# UITextField Font Weight Changing when Auto-Resizing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a UITextField in a storyboard with System Ultralight font of size 70. The label has a fixed width and is set to resize to a smaller font size if size 70 extends beyond that width ("Adjust to fit" is checked in the attributes inspector). This works, but the font is changing to System Regular when auto resizing. I've verified this with a print statement: `print(myLabel.font)` yields

```
Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7fa7cac3faf0> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Ultralight"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 70.00pt)
Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7fa7cac81ed0> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 64.00pt)
```

at the moment the label resizes. Note the change from ".SFUIDisplay-Ultralight" to ".SFUIDisplay-Regular".

Once this happens, the change is permanent. The label never goes back to being Ultralight, even when smaller numbers are input.

I found some other SO posts on UITextFields behaving oddly when edited, but not this particular issue. Any help on either why this is happening, or how to fix it would be much appreciated!

---

[image: font weight changing]

Comment: Sorry - can you tell me how to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @matt, 1. Add UITextField to storyboard. 2. Set font to System Ultralight, size 70. 3. Set minimum font size to something. 4. Add width constraint. 5. Run app, and type in more characters than fit.

Comment: Yep, no problem, I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, system font Ultralight weight will switch to a heavier weight automatically if we go below size 20 points. If this is happening at a larger point size, it's probably a bug and you should report it. Meanwhile, stick to Light, which is the lightest weight that won't auto-switch in this way.

Comment: Thanks matt. Unfortunately, switching to Light does not fix the problem. It still changes to Regular when resizing, even from 70pt to 64pt.

Comment: That's not what I see, but okay. Maybe my eyes deceive me. Anyway, file a bug report.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right about even Light. Argh. File away!

Comment: Alright thanks Matt. Glad to hear you were able to reproduce it, too. I've filed a radar.

Comment: Interesting! can you please point out to the Apple documentation link that says this? Thanks

Comment: @ImranRaheem it's in a WWDC video

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this issue in iOS 9.0 but the same code has no issues in iOS 10.